# Python list comprehension: Unlist if list contains only one element

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have got the following function:

```
output_names = [output.name for output in session.get_outputs()]
```

`session.get_outputs()` can return multiple multiple objects which I want to get the name property from. If the length of the list is 1, I want to `output_names` to be a value, not a list with a single value.

```
output_names = [output.name for output in session.get_outputs()]
if len(output_names) == 1:
    output_names = output_names[0]
```

I could do it like this, but this feels like a code smell. It there a more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Code smell is having two different types for a single variable (I mean either value or a list of values). If you do it, every time you use it you'll have to also check what type is currently contained. I would simply store a list with 1 element

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov: Yes, you make a good point there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about adjusting the way you construct `output_names` like:

```
outputs = session.get_outputs()
output_names = [output.name for output in outputs] if len(outputs)>1 else outputs.name
```

That said, mixing data types is not desirable, imo.